# Character Spacing

Tags: html, entity, entities, spacing

I was recently looking for a good way to space out sentences using html instead of using `&nbsp;`. One of the sites I found mentioned using `&thinsp; &ensp; &emsp;` entities. Would this be considered good practice? I did refer to w3schools to see if this was valid html but they only seem to mention the `&nbsp;` entity.

Answer (score 1):

In my eyes, using any spacing character is "bad" practice. This is because it may mess things up under different fonts/sizes/etc. conditions. I think you should use CSS for any type of spacing, unless it's something really basic (but 1-2 spaces max).

W3school only mentions `&nbsp;` because that's the most popular. Others aren't very common. In fact, I never heard of those other ones.

Comment: I currently use spans tags with classes and then in the css add `padding-right: 20px;` to add spacing in-between sentences, but I was just looking to see if there was a better way around this.

Comment: @Jordan `padding` is good because it will work well with all browsers and all platforms. I wouldn't worry about it ^_^.

Comment: I guess I will just stick with using span tags and padding then. I like to make sure I'm using good practice and this works well anyway. Thanks for the comment. :)

Comment: @Jordan Anytime. You can also use `<div>`s.

Comment: True but `<span>` is an inline element and my sentence I was spacing was inline.